# how to block attribute of parent from child element

Tags: html, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a div with attribute **data-toggle=collapse**. This div contains child element (a tag - a link) and i want that the **a** elemnt will not refer to the data-toogle attribute.

```html
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#someElement">
  <span>click here to collapse</span>
  <a (click)="anyFunction($event)">open new window</a>
</div>
```

i don't want that click on a element will collapse the panel.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use stopPropagation()  . see example below

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```js
$("a").on("click",function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation()

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#someElement">
  <span>click here to collapse</span>
  <a>open new window</a>
</div>
<div id="someElement" class="collapse">
blabla
</div>
```